# Trying to work out how an android app functon works out its response

Tags: android, frida

I'm not sure if i'm just not using the correct terminology as I have searched for ages trying to find out.

I have an application for android, I only have limited exposure to python and java a few years back with small projects in between. I am able to bypass ssl pinning and root detection using the available code snippits. Start Frida, etc

The app at some point calls to a server with a string that is worked out every call. If I view the decompiled code with jdax, I can see the return of the function by matching up parts of the string. But it is obfuscated, therefore, I am unable to see HOW the function returns the string.

I would like to be able to analyse this function and what data goes in and what is done with it to return the finished string. Or worst case duplicate it to test if the output is desired, Would need to see inputs so I could put some demo data there to test.

Am I correct in thinking I should be using frida for this? Or do I need Java tools to try and walk it back? If so, is there any recommended tutorials for that specifically? If I right click the function in jadx and find where its used, it just gets messy as goes to another function with no useful name and so on.

I have followed a few yt tutorials but they seem to be based on what function A is doing, rather than "How do we get this value?"

Thanks

Comment: If you don't understand the decompiled code then Frida is a reasonable next step. Hook the function that you are interested in and print input arguments as well as the return value.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the output but the functions aren't any meaningful name (All letters and overrides etc). If I can find the correct statring function and args either in JadX or Frida is there a way to lift all those referenced functions etc into a self contained program that I can use? Like someway to select function required and all obfuscated functions that are linked to it so I just put in args and get out string?

Comment: @JMGrice you can do something close to that. In Frida you can simply directly call the target function as many times as you like with any params you like. This can serve as a powerful tool in your process.
However if string deobfuscation is your main goal - usually there is a place in the code where you can simply dump to log from the memory (using Frida) which is much easier. You do need to be able to follow the decompiled code.